# filter:alpha breaks :hover in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

When using

```
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
```

on a div containing an unordered list which has :hover on the list items, IE8 will only activate the :hover event on the first item that is hovered over.

Moving up/down to another list item will no longer activate the :hover event.  This works in firefox however.

There is an example at http://www.ithinkimlost.com/paul/ese/test.html

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60)";
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
opacity: 0.60;
```

Some ideas that might fix it:

- reset the opacity on the `:hover`
- set an height on the `li`s
- add a `position` and remove the `clear`
- move `#homeOptions` above the `:hover` in the code

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately none of them worked.  I used jQuery .hover() to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: i think you should use the `:hover` on the anchors instead of the lis (of course remember to set display:inline-block to trigger hasLayout)

Answer (score 1):

try this sheet:

```
#homeContent {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#homeMainPic {
    background:url(main_pic.jpg) no-repeat;
    height: 216px;
}

#homeOptions {
    height: 216px;
    width: 300px;
}

#homeOptions ul {
    height: 216px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


#homeOptions li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    zoom:1;

    background-color:#009;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.60;

}

/* it is needed - don't ask why */
#homeOptions li:hover {
    background-color:#009;
}

#homeOptions a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.1em;

    border-bottom: 1px dashed white;

    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;

    padding-left: 30px;
}

#homeOptions a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
#homeOptions ul li img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right: 20px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.60;
}

#homeOptions {
    background-color:#009;
    height: 216px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;    
}
```